# Can't extract value from JsonValue object

Tags: c#, json, silverlight, deserialization

I am using System.Json dll in a silverlight project to parse a string to Json object. In this dll I have found a static method System.Json.JsonObject.Parse(string) that parse that return System.Json.JsonValue. I can see the result when I am in debug mode but I do't know tha way to extract the data. I can't find where I have to specify the type of my result or a way to handle it. 
Can anyone know a solution to this problem or another dll that can be added to silverlight to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

jsonObj is a List. 
You can do jsonObj[0] to access the first element.

```
jsonObj[0].existingOrders[0].TotalQuantity
```